# Webcam not Responding error ocurring when it tries to capture an image

Tags: python

The following program is to recognize the face that I am showing in the webcam. If in case, it doesn't recognize the face it should capture a screenshot. The program perfectly when I am showing a known person's face saved in my database. But, when I show it unknown person or I flicker the webcam so that it can't read the face encodings, the webcam suddenly "Not Responding".

In the program, you see in the While loop, the 'if statement is for recognizing the face and the while loop is for capturing the screenshot.' The if statement is running perfectly. But, when it enters in the else part the webcam is showing "Not Responding" in the window.

The code is a little bit long.  so, if you want then you can skip the above part. I specified the part where the problem occurring.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import face_recognition
    import os

    path = 'images'
    images = []
    classNames = []
    myList = os.listdir(path)

    print(myList)
    for cls in myList:
        curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')
        images.append(curImg)
        classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])
    
    print(classNames)

    def findEncodings(images):
        encodeList  = []
        for img in images:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
            encodeList.append(encode)

        return encodeList

    encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
    print("Encoding Complete.")

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1400)

    # you can skip the above part if it's irrelevant with the error. 
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
        imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        faceCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
        encodeCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, faceCurFrame)

        for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, faceCurFrame):
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
            faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
            print(faceDis)
            matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

            # The if statement is for recognizing the face that is being shown.
            if matches[matchIndex]:
                name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
                print(name)
                y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceLoc
                y1,x2,y2,x1 = y1*4,x2*4,y2*4,x1*4
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2-35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, name, (x1+6, y2-6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            
                cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
            # The else statement is for capturing the image if it doesn't recognize the face. 
            else:
                if cap.isOpened():
                    ret, frame = cap.read()
                    print(ret)
                    print(frame)
                img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                plt.imshow(img1)
                cv2.imwrite(f".\\temp_img\\temp.png", frame)
                print("Image Captured.")
                plt.xticks([])
                plt.yticks([])
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
        time.sleep(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add

> if type(img) != type(None):

after cap.read,your problem will be solved or you can add try and cath block at this part

> imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
> imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

it seems that the camera doesn't provide images as fast as the program process. At the else part you say to camera capture image and relase camera then close window.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import face_recognition
import os
import time

path = 'images'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)

print(myList)
for cls in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])

print(classNames)


def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)

    return encodeList


encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print("Encoding Complete.")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# you can skip the above part if it's irrelevant with the error.
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if type(img) != type(None):

        imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
        imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        faceCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
        encodeCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, faceCurFrame)


        for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, faceCurFrame):
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
            faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
            print(faceDis)
            matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

            # The if statement is for recognizing the face that is being shown.
            if matches[matchIndex]:
                name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
                print(name)
                y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
                y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 255, 255), 2)

                cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
            # The else statement is for capturing the image if it doesn't recognize the face.
            else:
                if cap.isOpened():
                    ret, frame = cap.read()
                    print(ret)
                    print(frame)
                img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                plt.imshow(img1)
                cv2.imwrite(f"images.png", frame)
                print("Image Captured.")
                plt.xticks([])
                plt.yticks([])
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: Thanks sahin Murat Ogur. So greatful to you bro. Worked perfectly.